# How to set image in byte array format in actionbar?

Tags: android, arrays, image, android-actionbar

I want to get user image like byte array from server and show this image instead of icon in Actionbar. I searched and founded, i can set image in icon with drawable like `getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.my_icon)` but i want to set image dynamically and i have not image in drawable folder . How can do this?

Comment: @sree Yes i searched but i can't found an answer

Comment: decode your byte array to bitmap, create BitmapDrawable from bitmap and use this method getActionBar().setIcon(yourBitmapDrawable);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
byte[] imageFromServer = getImageFromServer(); // assuming you get byte array from server
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageFromServer , 0, imageFromServer .length);
BitmapDrawable icon = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
getActionBar().seticon(icon);
```